# symfony1.4 - How to check if a translation item exists

Tags: symfony-1.4

How can I check if translation for meta.title exits?
The below statement do not work as it returns [T]meta.title[/T].

```
if(__('meta.title') != "")
```

Comment: `if(__('meta.title') != "meta.title")`?

Comment: no meta.title is a big text, if it is empty it returns [T]meta.title[/T], if not it is a sentence.

Comment: Se then `if(__('meta.title') != "[T]meta.title[/T]")`? Not sure I understand the problem here